# How to setup transitive jar dependencies for android+gradle

Tags: android, jar, compilation, gradle, dependency-management

I have a Android app project that depends on a vanilla Java project (':Common').  ':Common' depends on Guava which is located in the Java project's 'lib' directory.  The java code in the android project references Guava classes (e.g. the 'Lists' class) as well as classes defined within ':Common'.  The compilation of the android project fails due to not being able to find the 'Lists' class but is able to find the classes defined within ':Common' itself.  I know this is a configuration that would normally work in a pure Java scenario, but I can't figure out why it fails in this Android case.

NOTE: Adding 'compile fileTree(dir: '../Common/lib', include: ['*.jar'])' to the dependencies of the Android project fixes the compilation error, but obviously this is suboptimal (you shouldn't have to define dependencies in two places like that in gradle).

The build.gradle file for my android project looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {(omitted)}

    sourceSets {
        main.manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
        main.resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
        main.res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile (project(':Common'))
}
```

The build.gradle file for my java library project (':Common') looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
}

dependencies {
    compile (fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['*.jar']))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very easy way to solve this problem is to declare guava as a remote dependency of the Common project and have Gradle resolve it at build time. Remote dependencies are transitive and your application would get it by virtue of depending on Common.

Try adding these lines to the build.gradle of the Common project:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}
```

Then configure a base repository such as Maven Central:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

and remove the guava jar file from the lib/ folder.

Comment: Interesting, the dependency does indeed become transitive when made remote.  This is definitely a cleaner workaround than what I'm currently doing, but really I'm looking for a way to make the local  dependencies transitive (to make it easier to maintain Eclipse compatibility).

This inconsistent transience behavior does make it seem like it may just be a bug in the Android Gradle plugin though.